# reactive lapply for download pdf in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, lapply

I'm trying to export several ggplots which are stored in a list into a single pdf. Somehow I can't get it to work..

It seems to me the problem is in generating the list with lapply using reactive content because when I use a static dataset it all works fine. It doesn't work when using a reactive dataset..

So this works:

```
PlotDataFilt1<-filter(readRDS(paste0(get_lookup_path(),"/PlotData.rds")),Instelling=="agb")



    plot_list <-lapply(as.list(unique(PlotDataFilt1$variabele)), function(x) {

        ggplot(PlotDataFilt1%>%filter(variabele==x),
             aes(x=jaar, y = waarde, group=Instelling ,colour=Instelling),tooltip = c("x","y","group")) +
        geom_point()+
        geom_line() +
        labs(x=NULL,y=NULL)+
        ggtitle(x)+
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, face="bold", size=8))+
        theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
        theme(legend.position="bottom")  +
        scale_y_continuous(labels=function(n){format(n, scientific = FALSE)})
    })




    output$downloadPlot = downloadHandler(

      filename = 'graphs.pdf',
      content = function(file) {
        #print(plot_list()[[1]])
        pdf(file)

        arrangeGrob(
          for (i in 1: length(plot_list)) {
            print(plot_list[[i]]) },
                ncol =length(plot_list)
        )
        dev.off()
      }
    )
```

and this doesn't:

```
  plot_list <-  observe({

    plot_list <-lapply(as.list(unique(PlotDataFilt()$variabele)), function(x) {

        ggplot(PlotDataFilt()%>%filter(variabele==x),
             aes(x=jaar, y = waarde, group=Instelling ,colour=Instelling),tooltip = c("x","y","group")) +
        geom_point()+
        geom_line() +
        labs(x=NULL,y=NULL)+
        ggtitle(x)+
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, face="bold", size=8))+
        theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
        theme(legend.position="bottom")  +
        scale_y_continuous(labels=function(n){format(n, scientific = FALSE)})
    })

    return(plot_list)
  })


    output$downloadPlot = downloadHandler(

      filename = 'graphs.pdf',
      content = function(file) {
        #print(plot_list()[[1]])
        pdf(file)

        arrangeGrob(
          for (i in 1: length(plot_list)) {
            print(plot_list[[i]]) },
                ncol =length(plot_list)
        )
        dev.off()
      }
    )
```

EDIT: the trick is to put everything in the downloadhandler, see below:

```
output$downloadPlot = downloadHandler(
      filename = paste0("Plots_PaazPuk_", format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_"), ".pdf"),
      content = function(file) {

        plot_list <-lapply(as.list(unique(PlotDataFilt()$variabele)), function(x) {

          ggplot(PlotDataFilt()%>%filter(variabele==x),
                 aes(x=jaar, y = waarde, group=Instelling ,colour=Instelling),tooltip = c("x","y","group")) +
            geom_point()+
            geom_line() +
            labs(x=NULL,y=NULL)+
            ggtitle(x)+
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, face="bold", size=8))+
            theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
            theme(legend.position="bottom")  +
            scale_y_continuous(labels=function(n){format(n, scientific = FALSE)})
        })


        pdf(file)

        arrangeGrob(
          for (i in 1: length(plot_list)) {
            print(plot_list[[i]]) },
                ncol =length(plot_list)
        )
        dev.off()
      }
    )
'''
```

Comment: You should use `reactive()` and not `observe()` to pass data. Please read through the details section [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/observe.html)

Comment: I found the solution finnaly: the trick is to put everything in the downloadhanler itself. See edit